# Конструктор класса File не создает файл на диске

Tags: java, файлы

Пытаюсь создать новый файл по примеру из книги, но он не создается. Подобных примеров с использованием конструктора

`File f = new File("E://test.txt");`       в интернете много, но почему-то у меня на JDK 8 оно не работает.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File f = new File ("E://Workspace//create4.txt");

    System.out.println("File name : "+ f.getName());
    System.out.println("Parent: " + f.getParent());
    System.out.println(f.exists() ? "exists" : "does not exist");
    }
}
```

В итоге, вот, что получается:

```
File name : create4.txt
Parent: E:\Workspace
does not exist
```

Файла - нет. Знаю, что если набрать в try  `f.createNewFile();`  то все будет ок, но раз приводят примеры без него, то значит должно работать.

Comment: Если один из ответов отвечает на ваш вопрос, то его можно (и даже нужно) отметить "верным" нажал галочку слева от тела ответа.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, за совет, но я сразу же это сделал

Comment: Похоже, что вы просто поставили плюс ответу. А нужно нажать на галочку слева от ответа (под счетчиком голосов).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Конструктор класса `java.io.File` создаёт объект, представляющий файл на диске. Но конструктор не создаёт этот файл, а предоставляет некоторый интерфейс, который затем позволяет что-либо сделать. Например, проверить существует ли файл. Проще говоря, объект класса `File` после создания представляет собой только имя файла, независимо от его физического существования на диске.

Как верно замечено в вопросе, чтобы создать файл нужно вызвать метод `createNewFile`. Или же передавать объект типа `File` каким-либо функциям для дальнейшей работы. Но ещё раз повторю, что конструктор сам никаких новых файлов на диске не создаёт.

Comment: Спасибо! Только странно, почему об этом мало где написано.

Comment: Об этом написано в англоязычной документации - "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames". Во втором ответе есть на это ссылка. Но, к сожалению, эта не вполне понятная фраза далее не расшифровывается.

Comment: Интересно еще то, что если после File f = new File ("E://Workspace//create4.txt") добавить FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream (f);   и что-нибудь записать, то тогда файл благополучно создается )))

Comment: @MisterSmith Всё верно. Сложно писать в несуществующий файл, поэтому `FOS` подготавливает поток для записи, вызывая, в том числе, `createNewFile`.

Answer (score 8):

На мой взгляд, это недостаток наименования класса как `File`, поскольку по сути этот класс является абстрактным представлением пути к файлу или директории ([из документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html)):

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

Также добавлю цитату из книги "Thinking in Java" (4 издание, Bruce Eckel, в переводе):

> Название класса `File` обманчиво. Кажется, что он представляет файл,
>   но на самом деле это не так. На самом деле, более правильным названием
>   было бы `FilePath` — путь к файлу. Он представляет собой реально
>   либо имя конкретного файла, либо имя группы файлов в каталоге.
>   Если это группа файлов, вы можете получить их все, используя метод
>   `list( )`, который возвращает массив строк. Возврат именно массива, а не
>   одного из более удобных классов-контейнеров, имеет свой смысл:
>   количество элементов фиксировано, а если вам нужен другой список файлов,
>   вы просто создаёте другой объект типа `File`

Если посмотреть [исходный код конструктора](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/File.java#File.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29), то он очень прост:

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
       throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

Как видим, никакого файла на диске не создается.

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо!